# error in uploading a sql file with data

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following piece of code, which i think should work propelry:

```
drop table if exists patient;
drop table if exists pan;
drop table if exists device;
drop table if exists sensor;
drop table if exists actuator;
drop table if exists municipality;
drop table if exists period;
drop table if exists reading;
drop table if exists setting;
drop table if exists wears;
drop table if exists lives;
drop table if exists connects;

create table patient
    (number   numeric(20,2),
    name     varchar(255),
    address  varchar(255),
    primary key(number));


create table pan
   (domain  varchar(255),
    phone   numeric(20,2) ,
    primary key(domain));

create table device
   (serialnum      numeric(20,2),
    manufacturer   varchar(255),
    description    varchar(255),
    primary key(serialnum, manufacturer));    

create table sensor
   (snum    numeric(20,2),
    manuf   varchar(255),
    units   numeric(20,2),
    primary key(snum, manuf),
    foreign key(snum,manuf) references device(serialnum,manufacturer));
```

when i make `mysql> source proj.sql` 
    i get the following errors:

```
mysql> source proj.sql 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error (Code 152): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ()
Error (Code 1217): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'actuator'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'municipality'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'period'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'reading'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'setting'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'wears'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'lives'
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1051): Unknown table 'connects'
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'device' already exists
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

i don't know what to do anymore, so i am desperately looking for any help
thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're trying to violate a foreign key constraint when you delete a row that's still referenced in other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `device` table is referenced in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in some of the other tables. You can't delete this table while there are references to it. Change the order of the `DROP TABLE` commands so that the tables with the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints are deleted first.